# How to run spring boot application in windows which is developed in eclipse in Ubuntu os?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to spring boot. I have written code to display "hello world". 
HelloWorld1Application.java:
    package com.example.demo;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorld1Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld1Application.class, args);
}
}
```

AppConfiguration.java :

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class AppConfiguration {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

It runs fine in Eclipse ide. I have tried it in terminal n got proper output(java -jar target/HelloWorld1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar). 
Now I want to run this program in windows. How can i do that? Where can i find the bytecode of this application? How to execute it in command prompt of windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy `HelloWorld1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to windows
2. Execute `java -jar HelloWorld1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in command prompt

Note: make sure you have JRE installed on windows machine.

Comment: Thanks! I have installed jdk and set path environment variable. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set JAVA in your PATH environment variable.
Add location till bin in your path variable

```
C:>path
C:>PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin
C:>java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to set the path in environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install JDK and maven(set Java Binaries to your system environment)
2. on the project directory try `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have installed jdk. Then executed java -jar HelloWorld1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  command in cmd. I got the desired output.